# Is it possible to include a file and then remove it if the user does not need it?

Tags: php

For example, when *a.php* script runs, it will load *a_form.html.php*.

In this form, there is a link that when clicked, will include a file named *b_form.html.php*.

At this point, there are two forms on the page. *a_form.html.php* that was loaded when *a.php* was run. And below this form is another form named *b_form.html.php*.

However, if the user clicks the link by error and wants to remove the second form from the page, I have put a cancel button and wrote this script:

```
if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) 
{
    return; //this will remove the included file b_form.html.php
}
```

But this does not work. Any help guys? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Show the complete code.

Comment: sounds like using ajax and display/hide content in div..

Comment: what does not work? show some code that you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    include_once('a_form.html.php'); 

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']==='Submit')
    {
        include_once('b_form.html.php');
    }
?>

<form action="?" method="GET">
<!-- FORM ELEMENTS GO HERE -->
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
<a href="?" target="_self">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

This will load the initial form, and allow the user to submit the form. Once submitted, a querystring will be appended, with the element `action=Submit'`.

If the action querystring element is found AND it equals 'Submit', then it will load `b_form.html.php`.

If the user clicks the 'Cancel' button, this will reload the page, without the action=submit element, and therefore not include the b_form.html.php file.

Comment: You're a great help! However in your code it is a Cancel link, not a button though but it worked the magic :)

Comment: You could use a cancel button, try: `<input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel">`. Glad I could help! You can also change the form method to POST, just change your data requests from `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

No. The file will have already been processed by then.

Structure your logic so you know if you should include `a_form.html.php` before you get to the point where you need to include it.

In general, try to get all of your business logic processed before you run any of your display logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it . Use ajax there . write form code in ajax <div..  and when you will press cancel button at that time call ajax which will replace form in div with blank or your custom text .